# Batch echo the word return to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a for loop to iterate through a file and then output to another file, but I need to output the word "return" to the file.

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=1-2  delims=," %%a in (%filein%) Do (
echo if (%%a) return %%b; >> %fileout%
)
```

I keep getting "return was unexpected at this time"  I've tried variations of ^ and quotes and I've had no luck.
Does anyone know how to echo the word "return" to a file? Thank you

Comment: You forgot the second echo

Comment: Where did you put the `^`s? You should only need one before the `)` in `%%a)`.

Comment: it is the word return that is causing the problem

Comment: It is absolutely NOT the word "return" that is causing the problem; `return` is not a keyword in batch. The command prompt is seeing the `)` after `%%a` and thinking that _that_ is the closing parentheses for the `for` loop and trying to run `return` as a command. If you escape the parenthesis, the code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in (%filein%) Do (
    echo if (%%a^) return %%b;>> %fileout%
)
```

or

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in (%filein%) Do echo if (%%a) return %%b;>> %fileout%
```

The closing parenthesis `)` in your code to output by **ECHO** is interpreted by Windows command interpreter as end of command block of body of **FOR** command. The solution is escaping it with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character.

In second version the single command to execute by **FOR** is directly specified without using a command block at all.

Also the space between semicolon and redirection operator `>>` is removed as this space is also output by **ECHO** and therefore also written as trailing space into output file.

Comment: "Thank You" comments are considered non-constructive, as @Mofi said, you should check out the links and the FAQ section.